# Is there a single key in vim that both cancels the command I've just entered and takes me back to normal mode?

Tags: vim, vi

Because I'm still learning vim, I quite often find myself mistakenly entering the wrong command (for example, let's say I entered `ci{`, when I meant `ca{`). When I do this, vi enters insert mode and (in this case) deletes some text, ready for me to enter a replacement. If I hit `Esc` at this point, I go back to normal mode, but the text that the `c` command deleted remains deleted. Is there a way for me to go back to normal mode whilst undoing the full effects of that command? (I'm aware I can hit `u` after `Esc`, but I'm looking for one key/accelerated key).

Answer (score 7):

create the binding yourself.

```
imap <C-u> <esc>u
```

This would make the key press of control-u go back to regular mode and issue the undo command.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was hoping for a built-in command, but maybe this is what I'll have to do.

Comment: The ability to define your own mappings is the strength. Trying to build in every user's desires would never work. So vim let's you put in whatever desires you want.